# Typescript 'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules

Tags: typescript

I have a ReactJS project written in Typescript.

The project works fine but I get a ton of warnings like this:

```
src/components/Table/Table.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/context/AuthContext.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/data/cashflow.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/data/cashflowCategories.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/data/chart.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/data/constants/chartOptionsDropdownItems.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

src/data/constants/typeDropdownItems.js
  Line 1:1:  'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules  strict

...
```

None of these ts(x) files contain `use strict`.

```
export const typeDropdownItems = [
    {label: "Revenue", value: "REVENUE"},
    {label: "Expense", value: "EXPENSE"},
]
```

But ReactJS automatically puts it in the compiled js-file:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.typeDropdownItems = void 0;
exports.typeDropdownItems = [
    { label: "Revenue", value: "REVENUE" },
    { label: "Expense", value: "EXPENSE" },
];
```

Is there a way to solve or surpress these warnings? This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: _"ReactJS automatically puts it in the compiled js-file"_... I think you mean TypeScript / `tsc`. React doesn't compile anything